# RSP withdrawals and deposits

Tags: canada

I’m a senior (66), and I withdrew $20k from my RSP this year. They withheld the tax, but within the year I replaced the $20k. I have the room in my contribution, so **will I get all the tax money back, and will my income remain the same?** I receive a supplement from the government due to low income, and I don’t want to lose that.